# pgfplots: changing dashed line dash locations

Tags: pgfplots, color

Is it possible to have one set of dashed lines fill the gap of another set?

[image]

The black is just barely sticks out from the purple.  I would like the black to fill the gap in the purple.

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 500,
    no marks,
    xlabel = $\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel = $\scriptstyle y$,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -5,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5,
    ymax = 5,
    legend style = {
      at = {(-.35, 1)},
      anchor = north west}
    ]
    \foreach \u/\col in {0/red, 1/blue}{
      \expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\col, domain = 0:2*pi]
      ({(exp(\u) + exp(-\u)) / 2 * cos(deg(x))},
      {(exp(\u) - exp(-\u)) / 2 * sin(deg(x))});
    }

    \foreach \v/\colo in {0/OliveGreen, {pi/4}/Yellow, {pi/2}/RedOrange,
      {3*pi/4}/Black, {5*pi/4}/Purple, {3*pi/2}/White,
      {7*pi/4}/Brown}{
      \expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\colo, domain = -5:5]
      ({(exp(x) + exp(-x)) / 2 * cos(deg(\v))},
      {(exp(x) - exp(-x)) / 2 * sin(deg(\v))});
    }

    \legend{$u = 0$\\ $u = 1$\\ $v = 0$\\ $v = \pi / 4$\\ $v = \pi / 2$\\
      $v = 3\pi / 4$\\ $v = 5\pi / 4$\\ $v = 3\pi / 2$\\ $v = 7\pi / 4$\\};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an option called `dash phase` in the manual.

Comment: @percusse do you know where it is?  I searched `dash phase`, `dashphase`, and check all the `dash` but there was nothing about `dash phase`

Comment: It's in the PGF manual.

Comment: `texdoc tikz`. Manual for Version 2.10. section 15.3.2 page 157.

Comment: @percusse I tried many different options but there hasn't been a significant change.  Are there any examples for doing such task?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen I tried many different options but there hasn't been a significant change.  Are there any examples for doing such task?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `dash pattern=on <length> off <length>` you can give a uniform pattern for the dashed lines (gaps and strokes of the same length given by `<length>`); then all you have to do is to use `dash phase=<length>` to shift the dashed pattern for one of the plots; here's an illustration using a simplified version of your code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no marks,
    xlabel = $\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel = $\scriptstyle y$,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -5,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5,
    ymax = 5,
    legend style = {
      at = {(-.35, 1)},
      anchor = north west}
    ]
\addplot+[ultra thick,cyan,dashed,dash pattern=on 8pt off 8pt,domain = -5:5] {x};
\addplot+[ultra thick,orange,dashed,dash pattern=on 8pt off 8pt,dash phase=8pt,domain = -5:5] {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, the simplest solution is to have one solid line and superimpose the dashed one:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no marks,
    xlabel = $\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel = $\scriptstyle y$,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -5,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5,
    ymax = 5,
    legend style = {
      at = {(-.35, 1)},
      anchor = north west}
    ]
\addplot+[ultra thick,cyan,solid,domain = -5:5] {x};
\addplot+[ultra thick,orange,dashed,dash pattern=on 8pt off 8pt,dash phase=8pt,domain = -5:5] {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, incorporating this last approach to (part of) the original `\foreach` (I used `orange` and `Purple` since `Black` and `Purple` don't produce enough contrast):

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 500,
    no marks,
    xlabel = $\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel = $\scriptstyle y$,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -5,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5,
    ymax = 5,
    legend style = {
      at = {(-.35, 1)},
      anchor = north west}
    ]
    \foreach \u/\col in {0/red, 1/blue}{
      \expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\col, domain = 0:2*pi]
      ({(exp(\u) + exp(-\u)) / 2 * cos(deg(x))},
      {(exp(\u) - exp(-\u)) / 2 * sin(deg(x))});
    }

    \foreach \v/\colostyle in {{3*pi/4}/{orange,solid}, {5*pi/4}/{Purple,dashed,thick}}{
      \expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\colostyle, domain = -5:5]
      ({(exp(x) + exp(-x)) / 2 * cos(deg(\v))},
      {(exp(x) - exp(-x)) / 2 * sin(deg(\v))});
    }

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And now using dahed for both paths, and changing the pattern and phase:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false, dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 500,
    no marks,
    xlabel = $\scriptstyle x$,
    ylabel = $\scriptstyle y$,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -5,
    xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5,
    ymax = 5,
    legend style = {
      at = {(-.35, 1)},
      anchor = north west}
    ]
    \foreach \u/\col in {0/red, 1/blue}{
      \expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\col, domain = 0:2*pi]
      ({(exp(\u) + exp(-\u)) / 2 * cos(deg(x))},
      {(exp(\u) - exp(-\u)) / 2 * sin(deg(x))});
    }

    \foreach \v/\colostyle in {{3*pi/4}/{orange,dashed,dash pattern=on 8pt off 8pt}, {5*pi/4}/{Purple,dashed,dashed,dash pattern=on 8pt off 8pt,dash phase=14pt,thick}}{
      \expandafter\addplot\expandafter+\expandafter[\colostyle, domain = -5:5]
      ({(exp(x) + exp(-x)) / 2 * cos(deg(\v))},
      {(exp(x) - exp(-x)) / 2 * sin(deg(\v))});
    }

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it work so easily with a `\foreach` loop?

Comment: @dustin I guess so, specially the second option; draw the first one solid and the second one dashed. I guess you'll need a third variable in your `\foreach` controlling the line style.

Comment: @dustin please see my updated answer for an example using (part of) your `\foreach`.

Comment: ædustin new update!