# How to shift dashed pattern in pgfplots using "dash phase" : only in the plot, not in the legend

Tags: pgfplots, line

As mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131802/pgfplots-changing-dashed-line-dash-locations), one can use `dash phase` to shift the position of the blanks between the dashes of a plot. However, this also shifts the blanks in the legend.

Is it possible to shift the blanks only in the plot, while leaving the legend unchanged?

**MWE**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=3in,
height=3in
]
\addplot [black, dashed]
table {%
0 0
1 1
2 0
3 -.5
};
\addlegendentry{w/o dash phase}
\addplot [black, dashed, dash phase = 8pt]
table {%
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 -.5
};
\addlegendentry{w/ dash phase}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of `legend image post style`. You can use it to reset the `dash phase`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=3in,
height=3in,legend image post style={dash phase=0pt},
]
\addplot [black, dashed]
table {%
0 0
1 1
2 0
3 -.5
};
\addlegendentry{w/o dash phase}
\addplot [black, dashed, dash phase=8pt]
table {%
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 -.5
};
\addlegendentryexpanded{w/ dash phase}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]